# boost asio buffer lazy allocation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Async operations.

Now I pass preallocated byte buffer, for example:

```
s.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer( preallocated_pointer, preallocated_size ),
    _remote_endpoint,
    boost::bind(...)
    );
```

Is it possible to make lazy allocation for this and other calls?

Comment: Why do you mean by _lazy allocation_?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lazy allocation, or [allocating when the resource is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712683), can be accomplished using [`boost::asio::null_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html).  `null_buffers` can be used to obtain reactor-style operations within Boost.Asio.  This can be useful for integrating with third party libraries, using shared memory pools, etc.  The Boost.Asio [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) provides some information and the following example code:

```
ip::tcp::socket socket(my_io_service);
...
socket.non_blocking(true);
...
socket.async_read_some(null_buffers(), read_handler);
...
void read_handler(boost::system::error_code ec)
{
  if (!ec)
  {
    std::vector<char> buf(socket.available());
    socket.read_some(buffer(buf));
  }
}
```

Comment: nice answer -  I'll be able to use this myself :)

Comment: this answer has been really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: `null_buffers` has been deprecated since Boost 1.66.0: [_"(Deprecated: Use the socket/descriptor wait() and async\_wait() member functions.)"_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html)