# boost asio udp async_read_from buffersize

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was reading the [`UDP daytime example`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6.html) from boost asio tutorial. It uses a `recv_buffer_` and uses `async_receive_from()` to run the receiving loop.

```
socket_.async_receive_from(
    boost::asio::buffer(recv_buffer_), remote_endpoint_,
    boost::bind(&udp_server::handle_receive, this,
      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

What I don't understand is

```
boost::array<char, 1> recv_buffer_;
```

why its size is one ? what if the message received in more than one byte long ?

**EDIT**

as @Guy Sirton pointed I missed hsi part which was written in that page.

> Since we only provide the 1-byte recv_buffer_ to contain the client's
>   request, the io_service object would return an error if the client
>   sent anything larger. We can ignore such an error if it comes up.

But is there anyway to read the entire message without having a buffer size ? like looping `receive_some` by each character and storing in a string ?

Comment: maybe this is intended to receive byte per byte ?

Comment: "Since we only provide the 1-byte recv_buffer_ to contain the client's request, the io_service object would return an error if the client sent anything larger. We can ignore such an error if it comes up. " (from your link)

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I missed hat point. is here anything like `receive_some` that will loop the received message till it ends and keep appending to a buffer ? so that I don't need to keep a fixed size buffer ?

Answer (score 3):

A buffer size is required.

UDP preserves message boundaries.  When data is read from a socket, it will read up to the message boundary, even if the size of the provided buffer is smaller than the message.  When the message size is larger than that of the buffer, the error code will be set to `boost::asio::error::message_size`.

Either allocate a buffer large enough to read the maximum expected message size or use reactor-style operations to [lazily allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14207031/1053968) the buffer.

Comment: `When the message size is less than that of the buffer`. Did you actually mean *greater*?

Comment: @Dmitry, yes.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see that behavior on asio 1.18. It drops the packet entirely, no read, no error code.