# What is process memory usage?

Tags: visual-studio, memory, memory-management, diagnostic-tools

I have a 32-bit application developed in *Visual Studio 2017* and would like to understand what is process memory usage as shown in VS diagnostic tools.
As far as I understand the total memory usage of my app is about 330 MB but the used heap size is only 180 MB.

What is using the rest of the memory 150 MB ? 
Does high process memory usage have impact on application performance ? 
If yes, how can I reduce process memory usage ?

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio labels this "private bytes". If we take it at its word, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1984186/4137916) should explain what those are (and why they will not match your heap size, as that only counts heap in use). There are many interesting ways to define "the" memory use of a process on Windows, as there are many interesting ways of using memory (physical on disk, physical RAM chip, virtual memory -- reserved and committed, file mappings of executables -- shared and non-shared...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you discuss an App's memory space, you take into account a number of things and the heap is only one of them.

Because you already mentioned it, let's start with it. The **heap** is a dynamically allocated memory space. If you consider low-level languages like C/C++, when you call `malloc(...)` or `new Object(...)`, you allocate memory on the heap, when you `free(...)` or `delete X`, you free up the heap memory space.

An additional, very significant memory segment is the **stack**. As an oversimplification, this memory segment is responsible for "managing" the execution flow of our application and storing local variables. Because every thread in our process has its own execution flow, the operating system makes sure that every thread has its own stack. The default size of a Windows thread stack is 1MB.

Additional memory is occupied by additional segments of the application. Without going into much detail on those, Windows applications are PE files, and you can read about their format [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) and [here](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/articles/pefileformat.html). When you write your code, there are different things that are eventually stored into the binary file. The code itself is the most obvious component, but is not the only one. Static variables, some of which are initialized and some of which aren't (I won't go into detail to avoid confusion) are also part of the binary.

When you run the PE binary, the loader loads all those sections into the memory space of the created process. Over time, the application then creates new threads and allocates more memory.

As a gross and rough estimation, I would say that the amount of memory your process is using equals: heap + (thread-count * stack-size) + binary size

NOTE: I'm purposely ignoring advanced OS features, such as [paging](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/paging#:%7E:text=Paging%20is%20a%20function%20of,the%20implementation%20of%20virtual%20memory), [lazy allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712683/what-is-lazy-allocation#:%7E:text=Lazy%20allocation%20simply%20means%20not,an%20example%20of%20lazy%20allocation), [private heaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/heap-functions), etc.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption has always been additional memory is consumed by system dependencies that are not strictly included in the project yet are used by the process.

Additionally, you also have reserved paging memory, on windows this will cache all kinda of memory blocks for assumed use.

In my experience, the best way to minimise this overhead is to keep functions lightwiight (and 'functional'), making sure you're disposing of heaps/collections when not in use.

I hope that is of some help.