# memcpy() creates segmentation fault after too many iterations

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, memcpy

I am trying to create a multithreading library in c. Here is the [link to whole project](https://github.com/mjrusty/multithreading-example) (because pasting the code here would be too much text).

In the file `tests/MultithreadingTests.c` I am testing to the functionality of `lib/systems/multithreading/src/ThreadPool.c`. The function `add_work` adds any routine function the the work queue which utilises the functionality of `lib/sds/lists/src/Queue.c` and `lib/sds/lists/src/LinkedList.c`. In `MultithreadingTests.c`, `NUM_TESTS` defines the number of jobs I am adding to the work queue to be performed by `NUM_THREADS`

I am facing a weird issue with the code. If `NUM_TESTS` any number is less than `349,261`, the code works perfectly fine but any number higher than or equal to `349,261` results in segmentation fault. I tried to check where exactly the segmentation fault is happening and found that it happens in the `lib/sds/lists/src/Node.c` at line number 29 at `memcpy(node->data, data, size);`

The flow of code for the error is

- `tests/MultiThreadingTests.c` line 95 at `pool->add_work(pool, new_thread_job(routine, &arguments[i]));`
- `lib/systems/multithreading/src/ThreadPool.c` line 150 `thread_pool->work.push(&thread_pool->work, &job, sizeof(job));`
- `lib/sds/lists/src/Queue.c` line 54 `return q->list.insert(&q->list, q->list.length, data, size);`
- `lib/sds/lists/src/LinkedLists.c` line 107 `Node *node_to_insert = new_node(data, size);`
- `lib/sds/lists/src/Node.c` line 29 `memcpy(node->data, data, size);`

I am not sure why this issue is happening only when the number of jobs is higher than or equal to 349,261 but not when its smaller.

Comment: Probably `malloc()` is [being lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712683/what-is-lazy-allocation) and returning some thing other than `NULL` (you are checking `malloc()`'s return value, right?) even when there is no memory.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: I advise you to check error codes first. Without that, do not be surprised to see silent weird bugs. They might be a race condition somewhere. Is the bug deterministic?

Comment: @JérômeRichard The bug is deterministic. Also it doesn't occur while adding the 349,261st job in the work queue but while adding the very first job.

Comment: I updated one typo in the question. Issue is happening when `number of jobs` is higher than or equal to 349,261 and not `number of threads`.

Comment: @dbush I just installed valgrind and tried to run it though valgrind. When I run the executable directly `./build/testsmultithreading_tests` it creates segmentation fault but while running it through valgrind `valgrind ./build/testsmultithreading_tests` makes the program work perfectly without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In function `new_thread_pool()`, you neither

- test for allocation failure in `thread_pool.pool = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * num_threads);` nor
- test for thread creation failure in `pthread_create(&thread_pool.pool[i], NULL, generic_thread_function, &thread_pool);`

Trying to create 349261 or more threads on any system looks more like a stress test than a real life purpose. Test for errors and report them in a usable way.

`new_node` does not check for allocation failure either. Unless you instrument your code for this, you should use a wrapper around `malloc()` calls to detect allocation failure and abort the program with an error message.

The issue in your code is in the function `mt_test_add_work()`: you define an array of arguments with automatic storage:

```
Arguments arguments[NUM_TESTS];
```

This object is allocated *on the stack*, using 8382264 bytes of stack space. This is too much for your system and causes undefined behavior down the call chain where further stack usage actually cause a segmentation fault: a typical case of **Stack Overflow**.

You should allocate this object from the heap and free it before exiting the function:

```
Arguments *arguments = malloc(sizeof(*arguments) * NUM_TESTS);
```

Comment: Fair suggestion on the wrappers. Let me implement those. But I checked both of the those places and it doesn't seem to be the issue. Also - 349261 is not the number of threads but number of jobs in case that caused any confusion. Number of threads is only 10 (NUM_THREADS).

Comment: @Rusty: You write *If `NUM_THEADS` any number is less than 349,261* which does  cause confusion :)

Comment: My bad. Correcting it.

Comment: OK I found the problem. You are in the right place on stackoverflow :)